# php explode mysql row

Tags: php, mysql, row, explode

i have looked but am unable to find the answer i need.

i am trying to explode a row in mysql that containt multiple banner file names.

```
<?php
$str = 'one|two|three|four';

// positive limit
print_r(explode('|', $str, 2));

// negative limit (since PHP 5.1)
print_r(explode('|', $str, -1));
?>
```

i took that code from the php tutorial website. is it possible to use some form of echo command to print the file names in there from my mysql row.

eg that doesnt work is

```
<?php include '../connect/dbseries.php' ?>
<?php include 'Sbarray.php' ?>

<a href="series.php">back</a>

<?php
$str = print' . $row[Bannerfilenames] .';

// positive limit
print_r(explode('|', $str, 2));

?>
```

thanks in advance for your help
Aaron

Comment: $str = print' . $row[Bannerfilenames] .'; <--- check that line...

Comment: back . $row[Bannerfilenames] .Array ( [0] => 1 )   thats what it displays as on my site. what im looking for is a way to fix this error. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print all filenames in `$row['Bannerfilenames']`, either loop:

```
$names = explode ("|", $row['Bannerfilenames']);
foreach ($names as $name) echo "$name <br />";
```

or print them in a line separated by `,`instead of `|` with `implode`:

```
echo implode(", ", $names);
```

In case you can, re-design that database and **normalize** those tables, that means putting the filenames in an extra table. It is way easier to handle, and state of the art. Example:

```
table banner
----------------
banner_id
name
blabla
etc.

table filenames
-----------------
filename_id
banner_id  <--- store the banner_id from the above table here!
filename
blabla
```

Comment: thanks for the help worked great. the first one is easier becuase of how the database is created. now all i need to to randomly show just one of the file names from that. :) goes off to play :)

thanks for the help again. im sure i will be back sooner than i like to be.